# Prove that there are two non-computable functions whose product is a computable function

Tags: computability, turing-machines

prove that there are exists two partial non-computable functions  $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ whose product is a computable function $h(x)$ = $f(x) * g(x)$ for $\forall$ $x \in N$

I thought that we can just take two undecidable sets in $f$ and $g$ will be their
characteristic functions, but
characteristic functions are total, when we need to find partial functions/

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen added my thoughts. Please remove -1

Upd: thnx

Comment: A total function is a (special case of a) partial function. And if you really need it to not be total for some reason, can always modify it ad hoc.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  do you mean i can take 
characteristic function and modify it's dom ? But how, i don't understand a little bit.

Comment: If $f$ is a total function, let $f^*(x)=f(x)$ if $x$ is not zero and undefined if it is zero. Then $f^*$ is partial, and probably close enough to $f$ that it's still usable. Or if you want to keep all the information from $f$, let $f^*(x+1)=f(x)$ and $f^*(0)$ undefined. Anyhow, I don't think this is important for this problem. I think the most common answer to this problem will have $f$ and $g$ total functions, and I don't think that's wrong since a total function is a partial function.

Comment: If $f,g$ are properly partial, then $h$ is also only partial, isn't it? Or is "zero times undefined" considered zero in the context?

Comment: @Hagen That’s a good point: if “partial computable” meant “properly partial computable” and “computable” meant “total computable”, the question would be dead on arrival. (The usual convention is that anything times undefined is undefined.)

Answer (score 1):

So we take undecidable set $A$. $\neg A$ is undecifable too.

$f$ returns $0$ if $x \in A$ else returns $1$

$g$ returns $0$ if $x \in \not A$ else returns $1$

So $h = g * f$ is a total computable function which always returns $0$